# Footer background stopping before text finishes

Tags: html, css

I have a footer at the end of my website which is grey, but for some reason the background stops before the text finishes.

[image]

```css
#footer {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1% 5%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <span style="float:left;">
    <b>Contact Us</b><br/>
    Email: xxxxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com<br/>
    Contact Phone: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
    Contact Fax: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
    Company Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>
  </span>
  <span style="float:right;">
    <b>Follow Us</b><br/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. Floated boxes are taken out of the flow and don’t affect the parent box, floating all the children effectively makes the parent empty and it will collapse to zero height.

```
#footer {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
#footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much i totally forgot it didn't affect parents i added overflow: auto; and works perfect. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inspect feature of your browser to pinpoint the problem. (right click -> inspect).

probably because you are limiting the height.

Answer (score 0):

You are using padding in % which is causing problem and the the height is less

```
#footer{   

 background-color: #565656;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 37px;
    height: 22%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
        background-color: #565656;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 1% 5%;
        height: auto;  /* MODIFICATION */
        position: absolute;  /* MODIFICATION */
    }
```

Make `position:absolute;` and change `height` to `auto`

```css
#footer {
    background-color: #565656;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<span style="float:left;">
<b>Contact Us</b><br/>
Email: xxxxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com<br/>
Contact Phone: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
Contact Fax: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
Company Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>
</span>
<span style="float:right;">
<b>Follow Us</b><br/>
</span>
</div>
```

Here's working JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0op795ct/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floating elements are ignored when calculating the height of their container.

The best solution in your case, in my opinion, is to change the layout a bit and remove the `float: left` from the left span.

```
<div id="footer">
<span style="float:right;">
<b>Follow Us</b><br/>
</span>
<span>
<b>Contact Us</b><br/>
Email: xxxxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com<br/>
Contact Phone: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
Contact Fax: +86-769-xxxxxxxx<br/>
Company Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br/>
</span>
</div>
```